# iOS Visual Format Language using superview

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to set a view below the superview without the use of the pipe ("|"). The reason for this is because the superview isn't always the same as the pipe represents.

The code I have tried is this:

```
UIView *superview = self;
NSDictionary *metrics   = @{@"height" : @ROW_HEIGHT};
NSDictionary *views     = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view, superview);
NSString *hConstraint   = @"H:|[view]|";
NSString *vConstraint   = @"V:[superview][view(height)]";
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:hConstraint
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:views]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vConstraint
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:metrics
                                                               views:views]];
```

This doesn't display anything. When I change "[superview]" to the pipe it works but as explained above I can't use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint `V:[superview][view]` means "align the view's top edge with the superview's bottom edge" not "align the superview's top edge to this view's top edge" which is what you want. You'll have to construct the constraint using the more verbose constraint constructor (`constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`) rather than the visual format language.

Comment: I want to put the view below the superview, just like V:|[view. Or am I not getting your answer

Comment: I've tried to make my answer more clear. The syntax `V:|[view]` means "align the top edge of the view to the top edge of the superview", which is different than `V:[superview][view]`.

Comment: Very logical and fail on my part ;) Thank you